# Can I create VMWare image with Fusion 3 (Mac) and load on Workstation 7 (Windows)?

Tags: vmware-workstation

If I create and configure a Windows 2003 Server image using VMWare Fusion on a Mac, can I zip that up and copy it to a Windows system running VMWare Workstation and load it there?  Are there any issue with doing so?  Is there a minimum set of files I need (e.g. can I just copy the .vmdk and .vmx files?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this the other way round, and it worked without problems, but with XP and Linux guests.

Comment: I've gone that direction as well; assumed the reverse would be true.  I just gave it a quick try before fully configuring the guest and it all seems to work fine.  All I needed to copy were the .vmdk and .vmx files.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it.
Image of VMware Workstation and VMWare Fusion are compatible.